# Unable to find the API in the database

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am running the API Manager 1.10.0 
with MySQL 5.6 
on Linux RedHat 6.7.
WSO2Carbon starts without error. 
However when I browse API on the Publisher I've got "Error occurred while getting the APIs". 
No Problem in the Store, the API is listed in the Recently Added.

```
TID[-1234] [AM] [2016-05-11 10:21:01,338] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO} - Unable to find the API: admin-ApiCountry-1.0.0 in the database
```

When I select the am_api table I have

```
+--------+--------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
| API_ID | API_PROVIDER | API_NAME          | API_VERSION | CONTEXT        | CONTEXT_TEMPLATE | CREATED_BY | CREATED_TIME        | UPDATED_BY | UPDATED_TIME        |
+--------+--------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
|      1 | admin        | Informations_Pays | 1.0         | /Pays_Info/1.0 | /Pays_Info       | admin      | 2016-05-11 10:08:55 | NULL       | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+--------+--------------+-------------------+-------------+----------------+------------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I just had a similar issue ... a way around is to go into the /console , and delete the Api under Metadata , and try again.

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://hostname:9443/carbon/admin/index.jsp
Home  > Metadata  > List  > APIs 
Then delete the API's that are not displayed in the Store.
(Or delete all API's and publish them again)

Thank you JavaMastaRSA for the answer :)

Comment: this does'nt help me.

Comment: this worked for me. i also deleteed all apis files in repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api location